# arduino loRa module search tutorial

Tags: library

I recently purchased a LoRa module (https://it.aliexpress.com/item/1005002116232826.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.38c74c4dPnh2Gg) but I have not found any working tutorial for this model can you help me

Comment: this may help ... https://github.com/Lora-net/LoRaMac-node